# How to do constructor injection in Simple Injector if constructor takes another interface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to instantiate `HomedataAccess` class which takes string and an interface `IQueryManager` as constructor argument. How do I register it?

Till now I have done following and it works but I don't like this way:

```
 Kernel.Register(() => new HomeDataAccess("anandv4", 
     new SqlServerQueryManager(new SqlServerConnectionManager())));
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re doing can work just fine. There’s nothing wrong with that. Especially when your `SqlServerQueryManager` and `SqlServerConnectionManager` are only used within your `HomeDataAccess` class`.

In case however, the `IQueryManager` abstraction is used in multiple places, it becomes more problematic, because it would cause the registration to become duplicated and this could increase maintenance.

A solution might be to do the following:

```
Kernel.Register(() => new HomeDataAccess(
    "anandv4",
    Kernel.GetInstance<IQueryManager>());
```

The downside of this however is that this completely blinds Simple Injector when it runs its diagnostics. So this is not advised.

There are ways [to extend](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-parameter-injection-behavior) Simple Injector to so that primitive dependencies like these can be registered, but it’s usually a much easier solution to wrap the primitive value into a DTO. For instance:

```
public class HomeDataAccessConfig
{
    public readonly string UserName;
    public HomeDataAccessConfig (string userNamr) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName)) throw new ...
        this.Usrrname = userName.
    }
}

public class HomeDataAccess
{
    private readonly HomeDataAccessConfig config;
    private readonly IQueryManager manager;
    public HomeDataAccess(HomeDataAccessConfig config, IQueryManager manager) {
        this.config = config;
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```

This allows you to do the registration as follows:

```
Kernel.RegisterSingleton(new HomeDataAccessConfig("anandv4"));
Kernel.Register<HomeDataAccess>();
Kernel.Register<IQueryManager>(() =>
     new SqlServerQueryManager(new SqlServerConnectionManager()));
```

Comment: Thanks for going into details. I found out that I can abstract out simple username property into separate IUser interface. This helps out to do following:
Kernel.Register<IConnectionManager, SqlServerConnectionManager>();
Kernel.Register<IStoredProcedureExecutor, SqlServerQueryManager>();
Kernel.Register<IUser, User>();

Comment: Is that user name constant for the lifetime of the running application or does it change per request (as in: is it the name of the user who has triggered the current request)